# Synergy, OSX client, Windows 7 server - No mouse on client

Tags: synergy, osx-tiger

I have the following Synergy setup:

```
+------------++------------++------------++------------+
|     Mac    ||   Win 7    ||  Ubuntu 1  ||  Ubuntu 2  |
|c           ||s           ||c           ||c           |
+------------++------------++------------++------------+

Mac: OS/X Tiger 10.4.11 (G3)
Win 7: Windows 7 Ultimate x64
Ubuntu 1 & Ubuntu 2: Desktop 10.10
```

Now, everything works nicely between the Win7 server and the two Ubuntu machines.

What doesn't work is the Mac.

I am running the very latest Synergy (1.4.2, downloaded last night).

As far as the Mac is concerned everything should be working fine:

```
Synergy 1.4.2 Client on Darwin 8.11.0 Darwin Kernel Version 8.11.0: Wed Oct 10 18:26:00 PDT 2007; root:xnu-792.24.17~1/RELEASE_PPC Power Macintosh
Unable to connect to pasteboard. Clipboard sharing disabled.
2011-03-22 09:32:56.725 synergyc[406] Can't register screen saver connection 'com.apple.ScreenSaverDaemon'
started client
connecting to '192.168.0.202': 192.168.0.202:24800
connected to server
entering screen
leaving screen
entering screen
leaving screen
```

But it's just not interacting with the display at all (mouse doesn't move, keyboard does nothing).

I have tried running `ktrace` on synergyc and examining the dump, and the only clue I found was that it was trying to interact with the AccessibilityAPI which was disabled at first.  Enabling Accessibility has had no effect whatsoever (it has only stopped the failure to open /var/db/.AccessibilityAPIEnabled in the ktrace dump)

Anyone managed to get this to work in OS/X Tiger yet?

I used to run the server on OS/X and have the windows / unix machines as clients, but as my Windows is now a laptop I'd like that to be the server.

Comment: Hm I didn't know you could have 2 clients like this in a row (your 2 ubuntu machines).  I use synergy on a daily basis but have never put it at work on OSX so I guess I can't help here.  Sorry.

Comment: @Alain The latest synergy has a very nice interactive layout tool that lets you place your monitors on a 5x3 grid.

Comment: @Alain At least, the windows server does ;)

Comment: @Matt Jenkins, I see, I'm on the last 1.3 stable !  Wasn't bold enough for the 1.4, seemed to be a rewrite.  Took me some time to get it o work without DNS/DHCP (using Avahi and Bonjour instead).

Comment: @Matt Jenkins, why do you prefer the laptop to be the server? Have you tried having the Mac as the server (with this version)? Windows server with older version? I have only 2 machines, a linux with the server, and a windows client. I dislike the client behaviour when the server dies, so I would assume it is nicer to have it on a machine that is always on?

Comment: @MattBianco I prefer the laptop as the Mac is a G3 - it's just a tad slow.  One of the Ubuntus has no keyboard or mouse, and the other is a netbook and I find the keyboard too small for every day use. The laptop is my main workstation now.

Comment: @Majenko: You still have a draft "Please Do Not Touch Steve’s Pet Aligator!" that's not finished for the Super User blog, please let me know in the [Super User Blog Editor Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room) whether you are still planning to write this. Or should we re-assign or archive this draft? Then I can delete this comment afterwards... :)

Comment: @AlainPannetier yep - I've got [S][C1][C2] set up with C1 being OSX and C2 ubuntu.  It even knows to jump straight to C2 when C1 is turned off :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is older synergy versions for the mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ShareMouse](http://www.share-mouse.com/). It is way better than Synergy and does not even need a configuration to start sharing input.

Answer (score 0):

I use synergy successfully on my OSX machine.  I have OSX 10.5.8 (not sure which animal that is...) and have synergy 1.3.1.   My server machine is a Ubuntu (10.04) is also running synergy 1.3.1 and my other client is Ubuntu (11.10) running synergy 1.3.6.

So, try using synergy 1.3.x