# Mouse Disappears when Mac Is Client and Windows Is Server In Synergy While It Runs

Tags: windows, macos, windows-xp, synergy

When I run Mac OSX 10.4 as a client and Windows XP as a server.  I would move my mouse from XP to Mac and the mouse on the Mac would disappear until it returned to the XP Desktop.

I ran synergyc with --no-daemon to see what the problem was and they connect successfully, but only if I use XP's local IP address.  Also, it would show that the mouse was entering and leaving the screen.

I have used synergy successfully between two different versions of Windows, before, so I don't know if the XP setup is the problem or not.

Answer (score 5):

The Mac cursor issue is also discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/260761/synergy-osx-client-windows-7-server-no-mouse-on-client)

This is definitely a bug in the Mac software.

I have the same problem running Synergy server on Linux and client (v1.4.2) on Mac OS X 10.6.6

Workaround: The mouse cursor reappears when I hit Command-Tab to cycle between applications.

Comment: This is SUPER annoying :(

Comment: Confirmed it's still happening with the latest beta release 1.4.8 where the server is Windows 7 64-bit and the client is OS X 7.

Answer (score 0):

An additional workaround I've found (OS X Lion, 10.7.5) is that moving the mouse to the edge of the screen that contains the dock will bring back the cursor.

Additionally, but slightly more annoying, clicking the menu bar will also work.